# First time with linked lists - how do I name objects for insertion

Tags: linked-list, naming

Ok,

Dumb question time:

Usually with an array I have an object name: object[index] ...and if I have many of them then the index is what distinguishes each object from each other, hopefully, and usually in my case the index has a connection of to the reality of whatever the object is representing so I don't have to go hunting - the third one *is* the third one...

Now I have a job that requires a linked list as kind of queue (part of an LRU cache) - I just hit a question:

I'm about to declare the first object and add it to the linked list - but what do I call it ?

object ?  ...and I have lots of these somehow ?

object1 ? ...if this is the way, then how do I get that '1' there (and then '2' and so on)

I'm guessing the real solution is either really basic and I'll slap myself and/or pointers are involved ?

At the moment I'm just working out the project in terms of major algorithms in pseudoCode and every day go deeper into details. I'm yet to really learn C++ and am coming from a little Java course with and some basic ADT topics, but have no experience in practicalities. Any help really appreciated.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linked list objects are  called nodes, the first one would be head. Yes pointers are involved :) More info 
http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Linked_List

Comment: ahhhh, so the object cant exist independently of the linked list? unless, perhaps you made an array of them and made a linked-list of pointers to the array or ?

Comment: I wouldn't use arrays, the whole point of linked list is that it can grow dynamically as new nodes are added. The drawback is that you need to know the previous node to access the next one. you don't get random access only sequential. If you need to jump between nodes you can use double linked list, explained in the article above
What it comes down to is an object contains a pointer to another object.

Comment: I dont want to use arrays myself but I used that example as a potential way that objects could reside outside of the linked list. Say you wanted the objects to be in a linked-list for some algorithmical reason, but also needed access to them by name or by an index that was represented in and required by some other algorithmical paradigm - how is that achieved ? It's clear to me I'm missing some basic knowledge ;). Thanks for your words so far

Comment: Sure you can keep references to them elsewhere too, but the linked list concept is separate. Also if you keep references in multiple places be sure to clean up after yourself. C++ isn't garbage collected like Java

Comment: So a not too unworkable idea would be to add data to the linked list directly and not actually have any 'name' for it - other than it's pointer/memory address ...  I could then say hash it and store a reference/pointer in that hash-table...  The data in essence is nameless, expect for maybe the pointer name? If I'm building all this in a loop what do I name all the pointers ? Aren't I back at the same issue that I originally queried ?

Comment: You are right, a linked list is a container for homogeneous data What you could do is traverse the list storing a reference to an object and subsequentially manipulating it
Here's an example implementation using STL, maybe it's an option for you. Note that this implementation has slightly more features than a vanila linked list 

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialC++STL.html#LIST

Comment: Heh, I found that tutorial last night and saved it - thanks much for your time here - I'll get to work learning for now and see what happens. I'd upvote you but I dont have enough points yet